# Cloud Firestore : Is compound range query in more than 2 fields available now?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get ranged data like this.

```
ex) 10 < a < 20 ,  30 < b < 40
```

a and b both fields are index key now.

I think in this situation compound range query is the easy way.

But in Cloud Firestore, range queries are possible only for one field.

```
ex)   (possible) citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CA").where("population", "<", 1000000)

    (impossible) citiesRef.where("state", ">=", "CA").where("population", ">", 100000)
```

How can I range query in 2 fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As writing, this is not possible with Cloud Firestore and will likely never be available. Depending on your requirements though, there are workarounds by rethinking your data model and queries slightly.

## Option 1: Precompute a range

In this option you can add a field called `population_bracket`. In here, you essentially place the population value into a bracket you can test. Either decide by hand what the ranges are depending on your need, or use some automated method like `ceil(log(population))`

As an example the population of CA is roughly 39250000, so using the log method `ceil(log(population))` we get 8 which is what we'd store in `population_bracket`. If we're okay with the population range filter being changed to `<= 1000000`, then we can make the population filter a simple equality check using `population_bracket == 6`. CA gets correctly excluded!

## Option 2: client-side filter

In this option you make an educated guess which range filter will reduce the resultset the most, then simply do client-side filter of the results for the second filter (e.g, just ignore every state < "CA")